# Django: How to serialize a one to many relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I can't seem to figure out how to serialize a one to many relationship in Django, The information doesn't seem to even appear.

My models

```
class DataInfo(models.Model):
    component_id = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    component_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    data_id = models.IntegerField()
    data_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Data(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='data_owner')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    init_date = models.DateField()
    fin_date = models.DateField()
    data_info = models.ForeignKey(DataInfo, related_name="datainfo", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My View

```
class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.DataSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        data = models.Data.objects.using(db_to_use).select_related('data_info').all()
        return Response(self.get_serializer(data, many=True).data)
```

My serializers

```
class DataInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.DataInfo
        fields = ('id', 'component_id', 'component_name', 'data_id', 'data_name')

class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    datainfo = DataInfoSerializer(source="datainfo", read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Data
        fields = ('id', 'subject', 'init_date', 'fin_date', 'owner_id', 'data_info_id', 'datainfo')
```

I'm essentially just trying to do a join between Data and DataInfo, showing all the fields of Data and DataInfo in one view (not nested). I tried doing a select_related, putting a source attribute, nothing seems to work. The response I get is just all fields of the Data table with no fields of the DataInfo table. Am I missing something with the serialization?

Comment: What is `models.Conversation` and how does it relate to `Data`?

Comment: Sorry, typo, I changed it to be models.Data

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding `many=True` to where you add that `DataInfoSerializer`?

That is,

```py
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    datainfo = DataInfoSerializer(source="datainfo", read_only=True, many=True)
    # ...
```

(As an aside, `Data`, `DataInfo`, `data_info` and `datainfo` are rather terrible names. In particular, `related_name`s should be somehow plural or implying plurality, unless they're on OneToOneFields.)

Comment: I tried that as well, didn't seem to work either though

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    datainfo = DataInfoSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = '__all__'
```

Also, try explicitly mentioning the `data_info = models.ForeignKey(DataInfo, to_field=<data-info-id>)` in `Data` model.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most efficient way but something like below should work.

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    datainfo = SerializerMethodField('get_datainfo')
            
    def get_datainfo(self, obj):
      dataInfoObjs = None
                
      try:
        dataInfoObjs = DataInfo.objects.filter(data_info_id=obj.data_id)
        return DataInfoSerializer(dataInfoObjs, many=True).data
      except DataInfo.DoesNotExist:
        return []
```